# How to enable user self signup in django admin?

Tags: django

I am using Django admin for creating a simple user management portal. Is it possible for users to sign up using their email on Django admin?

Currently someone has to login to the admin interface and then create a user.

I tried searching for examples, but all the results are that regular user signup, without django admin

Comment: Yes. Your use case is atypical, and signup is not included in the django admin app. So you have to use the regular user signup. Just make sure that new users are created with `staff` permission so they are allowed to log into the admin site.

Comment: There's a bunch of third party registration apps available if you want extra features. https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/registration/